# puppeteer ignoring args pass for proxy pac url

Tags: node.js, proxy, puppeteer, chromium

I am trying to use pac file as an argument for puppeteer proxy settings as define here: https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/network-settings

`--proxy-pac-url=<pac-file-url>`

here is my code,

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async() => {
    const proxyUrl = 'http://{IPAddress}:{Port}';

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        args: [`--proxy-pac=url=${proxypacUrl}`],
        headless: false,
    });

    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://stackoverflow.com/');
    await browser.close();
})();
```

However, when I execute the code, the code just works and visit stackoverflow.com, but completely ignore

```
--proxy-pac=url=${proxypacUrl}
```

I know this because I can monitor the proxy logs. Proxy PAC URL file specifically says to use proxy for all traffic.

Here is my proxy pac file,

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {
    return "PROXY IP:PORT; PROXY IP:PORT";

}
```

When I change `--proxy-pac-url=<pac-file-url>` to `--proxy-server` and specify ip and port directly, the traffic goes through the proxy.

Can someone please let me know what I am doing wrong with Proxy PAC URL?

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your code

`--proxy-pac=url=${proxypacUrl}` should be `--proxy-pac-url=${proxypacUrl}`.

Unfortunately fixing it won't help because proxy pac files aren't supported in headless chromium, here is an [issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=765245).